# Qt designer and Creator

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator, designer

I have experience in C++, but I am totally new to Linux programming.

I figured out how to build a GUI, in Qt Designer, but I want to subclass QTextEdit before I create the interface, so I can create my own slots.  If I use Qt Creator first, then my code doesn't show up when I switch back to Designer.

Could someone please explain the relationship between Designer and Creator, and how I maneuver between the two?

Answer (score 1):

to keep things simple..

- QT Creator it's nothing more nothing less then just an IDE (btw it has Qt Designer components build in, but I still prefer standalone designer).. Editor, front-end to GDB, project management.. mostly everything you can find in other IDE's
- QT Designer - user interface editor which produce an XML files which can be used in two ways. 1) process them with MOC preprocessor (part of Qt) which generates you C++ classes for your user interface components 2) (which I prefer much more) load them runtime